# SVG fullscreen Javascript working correctly in FireFox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, svg, webkit, fullscreen

I'm experiencing an error when trying to make an SVG tag fullscreen using Javascript on my site. I've been told by others on the team that this used to work correctly, but has broken at some point in the past. On Firefox, the code works perfectly, and the SVG image becomes fullscreen, but on Chrome, the whole page goes fullscreen, and the SVG gets moved to the bottom left corner of the screen and seems to be placed on top of some of the other elements of the page.

I'm using the following code to handle the fullscreen action, which is hooked up to a button event listener:

```
function fullscreen() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myFullscreenSVG");
  var isFullScreen = (document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement !== null) ||
  (document.webkitFullscreenElement && document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null) ||
  (document.mozFullScreenElement && document.mozFullScreenElement !== null) ||
  (document.msFullscreenElement && document.msFullscreenElement !== null);
  if (!isFullScreen) {
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
      element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
      element.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
      console.log('Failed to enter fullscreen mode on dependency visualization SVG');
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else {
      showAlert("Exit fullscreen failed; Press [ESC] to exit");
      console.log('Failed to exit fullscreen mode on dependency visualization SVG');
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried everything I could think of, such as adding CSS for webkit-fullscreen elements to make width and height 100%, position fixed, and top 0, as this seems to be what others have done, but so far nothing has worked. What might be causing this to work incorrectly on Chrome? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've found a Chrome bug, report it to Chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: I don't think this is a Chrome bug, I think this is an issue with my code somehow. I have been able to make other non-svg images fullscreen in Chrome with the code above, I'm just having this issue with SVG files.

Comment: Pretty sure this is indeed a bug (or misfeature, anyway) in Chrome. You can work around it by wrapping your `<svg>` element inside a `<div>` or similar, and calling `requestFullscreen()` on the div instead.

Comment: Yep, after lots of testing I did find this to be a Chrome bug and solved it just about how you suggested. Unfortunate, but at least it's something that can be worked around.